# How to display text left side and icon on right side in html css?

Tags: html, css

I have to display text left side and font awesome icon on the right side.Now I am getting all font awesome icon below of text.I think this may pretty simple, but still, I can not get it to work.Would you help me in this?

```css
.top-contact-menu {
  background-color: #6aaf08;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}
.top-contact-menu h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
}
ul.address-top-menu {
  list-style: none;
}
ul.address-top-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.address-top-menu li:after {
  content: '|';
  color: #fff;
}
ul.address-top-menu li:last-child:after {
  content: ' ';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="top-contact-menu">
  <h2>we are open:10am to 8pm</h2>

  <ul class="address-top-menu">
    <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
    </li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: try `float: left` on both of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[Float](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)**. It will help you to push content to extreme right.

```css
.top-contact-menu {
  background-color: #6aaf08;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}
.top-contact-menu h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.address-top-menu {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
ul.address-top-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.address-top-menu li:after {
  content: '|';
  color: #fff;
}
ul.address-top-menu li:last-child:after {
  content: ' ';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="top-contact-menu">
  <h2>we are open:10am to 8pm</h2>

  <ul class="address-top-menu">
    <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
    </li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: nice and clean answer !

Answer (score 1):

Use `float` to handle the alignments. Check `.top-contact-menu` and `ul.address-top-menu`

```css
.top-contact-menu {
  background-color: #6aaf08;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.top-contact-menu h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: left;
}
ul.address-top-menu {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
ul.address-top-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.address-top-menu li:after {
  content: '|';
  color: #fff;
}
ul.address-top-menu li:last-child:after {
  content: ' ';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="top-contact-menu">
  <h2>we are open:10am to 8pm</h2>

  <ul class="address-top-menu">
    <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
    </li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to this..

```
.top-contact-menu h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
}


 ul.address-top-menu {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox over the class .top-contact-menu

```
.top-contact-menu {
        background-color: #6aaf08;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5px 0px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-content: flex-start;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
.top-contact-menu:after{content:'';display:table;clear:both;}
.top-contact-menu h2{float:left;}
.address-top-menu{float:right;}
```